# Any idea why this request works at curl and not in java?

Tags: java, api, curl, woocommerce

I am trying to use the woocommerce APi with java,but it returns 403.When I try the same request by curl it works fine.

Already tried adding/removing request properties

Java class:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    String CONSUMER_KEY="consumer_key";
    String CONSUMER_SECRET="consumer_secret";
    String authString = CONSUMER_KEY + ":" + CONSUMER_SECRET;
    byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
    String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    try {
        String url ="https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products";
        URL url1 = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic "+authStringEnc);
        conn.setRequestProperty("header","content-type:application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
        String response= GzipUtil.unzip(bytes);
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }

}
```

Curl request:

curl https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products \
    -u {consumer_key}:{consumer_secret}

Any idea how to resolve this? Thank you

Comment: What exception will be thrown? What is the error? What Problem do you want to solve?

Comment: The response code is 403. The expected response code is 200. So the problem is that even if I provide the correct credentials, the response is not the expected. Same request done by curl works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some servers expect a User-Agent header to be present in the request to consider it as a valid request. So can you try to add that to your request?

```
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "My-User-Agent");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The weird thing is that I tried it before and it didn't work,(maybe because I tried with many user agents), now that I tried with Mozilla/5.0, it worked.